# Cards expiring in 2020 are returning "Card has expired"

Tags: wordpress, authorize.net, omnipay

For customers whose credit cards expire in 2020, this is the message they are getting after submitting their credit card for payment:

> Could not process payment.
>       Card has expired
>       Please check the details and try again

Authorize.Net is never even seeing the transaction, so I know it's the plugin that is returning this message.

I found "Card has expired" on line 143 of lib/omnipay/vendor/omnipay/common/src/Omnipay/Common/CreditCard.php of the cj-paid-content-packages plugin for WordPress.

> if ($this->getExpiryDate('Ym') < gmdate('Ym')) { 
>               throw new InvalidCreditCardException('Card has expired');
>           }

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Try echoing out/logging the result of `$this->getExpiryDate('Ym')` and `gmdate('Ym')`. One of these values may be returning a bad result (I suspect the former)

Comment: Thanks for responding @james-paterson. I did this: `throw new InvalidCreditCardException($this->getExpiryDate('Ym'). ' < '.gmdate('Ym') );` and now I'm getting this: `200211 < 201610`. Not really sure what that means.

Comment: The year is being interpreted as 2002 rather than 2020. I think if you showed us where the date was being set, that may help diagnose the problem. This is an old question, so if you did solve it, it would be nice not to leave us hanging.